# C#: how to compare "Size" along with new item

Tags: c#

I have 2 List classes below,

```
public class OldList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
public class NewList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have data from 2 class likes,

```
var oldList = new List<OldList> {
            new OldList { Name = "F1", Size = 374 },
            new OldList { Name = "F2", Size = 125 }
        };

        var newList = new List<NewList> {
            new NewList { Name = "F1", Size = 374, },
            new NewList { Name = "F2", Size = 126,  },
            new NewList { Name = "F3", Size = 13,  }
        };
```

I would like to filter `newList` to retrieve all new items (e.g. "F3") and also all existing items where `Size` of `newList` is greater than `Size` of `OldList` (e.g. "F2").

For "F1" the Size is the same, hence I want to ignore.

Below code gave me result "F3", how to also get "F2"?

```
var X = newList.Where(p => !oldList.Any(l => p.Name == l.Name));
```

Comment: You are comparing names, while you seems to need to compare by Size. That is all. BTW, why do you have two classes with the same properties?

Comment: "so that it only contain new items (F3) and Size of newList item is greater than OldList (F2)." What does that mean? Do you want all F3 items _if_ F2(new) > F2(new), or do you also want to include the F2 item _if_ it if greater than the old F2 item?

Comment: wish to include `F2` also

Comment: I clarified the text, I think it should be clearer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an additional condition for "same name, increased size" into the `.Where` statement, like this:

```
var X = newList.Where(
    p => !oldList.Any(l => p.Name == l.Name)
       || oldList.Any(l => p.Name == l.Name && p.Size > l.Size)
);
```

Comment: that will return `true` if there is `at least` one item `F2` with `Size` lower than that in the `OldList`. I thought the requirement was that `Size` in oldlist is higher than all sizes in `newList`.

Comment: I assumed that Names in each list are unique, and that newList is an updated version of oldList, containing new entries + existing entries with sometimes bigger sizes, both of which are then to be delivered.

Answer (score 2):

Try this?

```
var result = newList.Where(i => !oldList.Any(l => i.Name == l.Name) 
|| i.Size > oldList.Where(x => x.Name == i.Name).Select(x => x.Size).Max());
```

Note: performance of this won't be great and this may not translate to SQL if you're using ORM.

Comment: Shouldn't the final `l.Name` be `i.Name`?

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi yup